# E: Unable to locate package php5-gmp

Tags: apt, software-installation, xubuntu

After I try

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gmp
```

This is what I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package php5-gmp
```

Answer (score 2):

The output you're getting `E: Unable to locate package php5-gmp` is telling you the package isn't in the repository.  You can verify by running this:

```
$ apt-check search php5-gmp
```

If the package exist, you will see some information about it.  If it doesn't there won't be any output.

You can broaden your filter, for example in this case, remove the `-gmp` and analyze what you find.  On a default installation your response will be similar to:

```
$ apt-cache search php5
bluefish - advanced Gtk+ text editor for web and software development
phing - PHP5 project build system based on Apache Ant
php-auth - Creating an authentication system
php-doc - Documentation for PHP5
php-http-request2 - Provides an easy way to perform HTTP requests
php-letodms-lucene - Document management system - Fulltext search
php-memcache - memcache extension module for PHP5
php-memcached - memcached extension module for PHP5, uses libmemcached
php-net-dns2 - PHP5 Resolver library used to communicate with a DNS server
phpunit - Unit testing suite for PHP5
```

Alternatively you can use a regex filter for your `apt-search`.  In this case you want `php` and `gmp`.  So you could use:

The following and get the following results:

```
$ apt-cache search php.*gmp
php-gmp - GMP module for PHP [default]
php7.0-gmp - GMP module for PHP
```

**The resolution in this case is to use this to install your package:**

```
$ sudo apt install php-gmp
```

By the way, `php7` is the default `php version` for Ubuntu 16.04.1.

---

**If this is a fresh install** make sure your repository cache is up-to-date.  YOu can do this with:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Comment: My ubuntu version is  **Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS**.
After I tried  - **$ apt-cache search php.*gmp** nothing happened.It shows the same when I try to install php-gmp --> **E: Unable to locate package php5-gmp**

Comment: @LorencDoda Verify your repository is up to date.  Perform the commands in the last section of the answer.

Comment: After I did the commands I have the same error.
This is another error while I was making the upgrade ;
**E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**

Comment: @LorencDoda Will you add the command and full error to your question.  The line you mention here doesn't have enough information to analyse.